# zend get posted variables from static form from the view file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-view

Ok so i tried using zend form but what i'm trying to accomplish is way too much for me to handle zend form. I'll try to describe it in a few lines maybe you have a solution for me if not you will understand why i chose to use a form in a view file.

I have a form for searching products in a database. THe search is done using autocomplete (custom made). When the user presses "Add product to list" the product is being added to a div in the form, creating the impression of a list. I want to submit this (the newly added inputs in the form) to the controller and process the form. I don't know how to do this, or it is not possible, have no clue yet but the zend form gave me so many headaches that i am very close to stop using it.

So i have designed a static form, in my view file. I have my jquery stuff there, i add data (hidden input fields and checkboxes) and i want to post to my controller. The question is how do i get the $_POST array in my controller?

Comment: What you are doing is not a recommended practice. See this tread to see why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248134/zend-form-when-should-be-form-created-in-view-and-not-in-controller/3248884

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer you as better as I can givin how your question is vague.

If you have a html form on your webpage all you need to do is set its action to your controller:

```
action="mycontroller/myaction"
```

And in case its not:

```
method="post"
```

And in your controller in fact this would work:

```
$_POST['param_name']
```

but the Zend way would be in your controller's action:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
   $data = $this->_request->getPost();
   Zend_Debug::dump($data);
}
```

Hope this help. If you need more details edit your question to make ti more clear.

Also it does'nt matter if the form was created with Zend_Form or by hand that code will work regardless.